# Jquery ajax form submit response getting alert automatically

Tags: php, ajax, jqueryform

I am trying to upload an image using ajax form. Image upload is success. But the ajax response getting alerted automatically with a blank popup saying 'The page at www.xxx.com says'.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$('#profileImg').die('click').live('change', function()         
{
$("#profileform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview_profile', 
 beforeSubmit:function(){ 
 $("#profileloadstatus").show();
 $("#profileloadbutton").hide();
 }, 
success:function(s){
 $("#profileloadstatus").hide();
 $("#profileloadbutton").show();
}, 
error:function(){ 
 $("#profileloadstatus").hide();
 $("#profileloadbutton").show();
 $('#profileform').reset();
} }).submit();
if(!s)
{
    $("#profileform")[0].reset();
}
});
```

HTML FORM

```
<div id="preview_profile"></div><form id="profileform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='message_profile_ajax.php'>
                    <div id="preview_prof"></div>
                    <div id="profileloadstatus" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
                                    <img src='images/wall_icons/ajaxloader.gif'/> Uploading....
                                    </div>
                     <div id="profileloadbutton">               
                     <input type="file" id="profileImg" name="profileImg">
                     </div>
                     <input type="hidden" id="profvalues" value=""  />
                     </form>
```

Php code

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';


function getExtension($str) 
 {

     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 

     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
 }

 function getImangeName($str) 
 {

     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 

     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,0,$i-1);
     return $ext;
 } 

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['profileImg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['profileImg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                 $ext = getExtension($name);
                 $imageName = getImangeName($name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = $imageName.time().$uid.".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['profileImg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $profile_path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                 $data=$Wall->Profile_Image_Upload($uid,$actual_image_name);
                                 if($data)
                                {

                                     echo '<img src="'.$profile_path.$actual_image_name.'" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />';

                                }
                            }
                        else
                         {
                            echo '<b>Sorry, </b>Falied to upload your file!';
                         }
                    }
                    else
                    echo '<b>Sorry, </b>Image file size must be less than 1 MB!';
                    }
                    else
                    echo '<b>Sorry, </b>Invalid file format!';  
            }

        else
            echo '<b>Sorry, </b>Please select image..!';

        exit;
    }
```

?>

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: It's probably not this code which calls the alert. Can you show the code in `message_profile_ajax.php`? Do you have other relevant JS code?

Comment: I have checked the included js file. No other alerts in it. Have updated the question with message_profile_ajax.php code

Comment: This doesn't look like all the JQuery...Where is the `s` variable being declared?

Answer (score 0):

Check jquery.wallform.js

```
        //return data;
        // Modification www.9lessons.info
        var exp = /<img[^>]+>/i;
        expResult = data.match(exp);
        if(expResult == null) {
            alert(data);
        } else {
            $(options.target).prepend(data);
        }
       $("#photoimg").val('');
       // Modification End www.9lessons.info
```